# How can I hide a div if a specific div does not exist using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class=“orange” style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 160px;">
    <div class=“apple” group="group" config="config" context="context"  applet="applet" slider-items="sliderItems" >
        <!-- ngRepeat: obj in sliderItems --> <!-- ngIf: sliderItems.length > 0 -->
        <div ng-repeat="obj in sliderItems" class=“grape" ng-if="sliderItems.length > 0" ng-show="ready" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative;  width: 240px;" aria-hidden="false">
```

How do I hide class "orange" if the div with class "grape" does not exist or is hidden?  I believe this can be done with a line of jquery.

(If not possible, how do I hide class "orange" if the length of sliderItems is 0?)

Comment: `“ ”` !== `" "` - Please use a better code editor.

Answer (score 1):

The variable sliderItems is declared only in the line 2?

If not, you can add `ng-if="sliderItems.length > 0"` in `div class="orange"` too, like you did on the line 4.